# Are there any free Sybase ASE 12.5x ODBC Drivers available, or does anyone have any experience with any paid ones?

Tags: odbc, sap-ase

Are there any free Sybase ASE 12.5x ODBC Drivers available, or does anyone have any experience with any paid ones? I'm looking for a fast and simple solution, but don't necessarily want to pay big bucks.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/).  ASE uses the TDS wire protocol for connections.  FreeTDS looks like it does TDS in C++ as an ODBC driver.

[Original answer, but useful for other people looking for a Java solution:]
jConnect.  I just downloaded it from Sybase [directly](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1041013).  ([here's the manual](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.dc39001_0605/pdf/prjdbc.pdf))  Its a type 4 jdbc driver that uses the TDS protocol.  The jdbc url for connections is a little funky.

Here's an article [comparing](http://iablog.sybase.com/paulley/2009/03/differences-between-jconnect-and-the-ianywhere-jdbc-driver-part-un/) the 2 official Sybase drivers, jConnect and iAnywhere.

Hm, I see you specified ODBC, now that I've posted this.  [Heres](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc_jdbc_gateway/) an ODBC-JDBC bridge that you could use.  I see what you mean, there are a lot of [pay](http://download.cnet.com/OpenLink-Lite-Edition-ODBC-Driver-for-Sybase-TDS/3000-2065_4-51337.html) ODBC drivers out there, but some have free trials... your best bet might just be to use the free jdbc driver and a free odbc-jdbc bridge.

Wait, you must have an installation of ASE somewhere already if you are trying to connect to it.  There would have been one that came with that.  Also, some of the developers editions you can download from Sybase are free.

Comment: Thanks for the information, John. We'd prefer not to use JDBC, as we're interfacing via .NET only. Sorry, I should have clarified this in the question.

Comment: Sure, looks like FreeTDS might work.

Comment: Thanks again, John. It looks like FreeTDS is a Unix/Linux only environment, though.

Comment: I was just looking through the source code for it, and theres a win32 section.  I'm not sure what all is in there though.

Comment: I don't have visual studio, but theres a MSVC6 folder that contains FreeTDS.dsp and FreeTDS.dsw.  Check that out.

Comment: Heres a windows installer for the FreeTDS dll.  http://freetds.sourceforge.net/FreeTDS%20Setup%200.64.1.exe

Answer (score 2):

[FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/) will work on Win32 platforms as well as Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to the Sybase client drivers - https://apps.state.or.us/tech/htdocs/sybase.html

I realise it's a bit late for you, but for others this might save them a bit of pain.

It is pretty ridiculous downloading 500mb for an ODBC driver, but there you go.